# UIActivityViewController compose view quickly dismisses itself when trying to share video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to share a video file using `UIActivityViewController` and it seems to work initially but the compose view quickly appears and then dismisses itself instantly.

So far in my testing on my iOS device (iPhone 7) I have run into this same problem for share actions: 'Message', 'Mail', 'Add to iCloud Drive' and 'Save to Dropbox'.

For example, when I select to share via Message I get this sequence of lines in the debug console

> SLComposeViewController _isAvailableForMediaShareExtension: will
>   check availability
>   SLComposeViewController _isAvailableForMediaShareExtension: waiting
>   for signal
>   SLComposeViewController _isAvailableForMediaShareExtension: got
>   availability 0 error (null)
>   [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add
>   any new fences due to CA restriction

My share function:

```
func share() {
    let objectsToShare: URL = self.videoURL
    let sharedObjects: [AnyObject] = [objectsToShare as AnyObject]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems : sharedObjects, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.postToTwitter]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any one know what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIActivityViewController` is scoped to the function and is killed when the function completes.

Move the variable `activityViewController` to an instance var, and it will survive.